# Pandas OLS - pulling params not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I have Pandas OLS lines of code that are working correctly, but am unable to pull the params to use in another related function:

```
ES_15M_LR = pd.ols(y = ES_15M_Last_300_Periods['Close'], x = ES_15M_Last_300_Periods['Date'])
```

The above code works great, but when I try to pull params from this I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'params'
```

For instance, I tried:

```
ES_15M_LR.params
```

As well as:

```
ES_15M_LR.params.x
```

...to pull the x coefficient (slope). That gets the same error as stated above. I can however see that the stats are working as expected:

[image]

I just don't seem to be able to pull the parameters automatically, which I need to have as a variable for other functions. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used OLS with pandas, but it seems that it used to exist in pandas and moved to the statsmodel package. It seems that the documentation is also out of date or incorrect, but `ES_15M_LR.beta` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's highly recommended that you use statsmodels because...

> `pandas.stats.ols`, `pandas.stats.plm` and `pandas.stats.var` routines are
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version ([GH6077](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6077): *MIGRATE: **move stats code to statsmodels / deprecate in pandas** #6077*)

And regarding `param` access,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

model = sm.OLS(df['A'], df['B'])
fit = model.fit()

print fit.params

B    0.724865

print fit.summary()

                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      A   R-squared:                       0.533
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.528
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     113.0
Date:                Thu, 16 Feb 2017   Prob (F-statistic):           4.66e-18
Time:                        10:27:13   Log-Likelihood:                -509.62
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                             1021.
Df Residuals:                      99   BIC:                             1024.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B              0.7249      0.068     10.629      0.000       0.590       0.860
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        3.447   Durbin-Watson:                   1.724
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.178   Jarque-Bera (JB):                2.856
Skew:                           0.301   Prob(JB):                        0.240
Kurtosis:                       2.432   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================
```

And check [sm.add_constant()](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.add_constant.html) also.